# application.html.erb to render different partial depending on the page user is on

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I would like to show a different header menu depending on which page of the site a user is on. So basically in Rails' `application.html.erb` I want something like:

```
<% if "user is op page x" %>
  <%= render 'layouts/header1' %>
<% else %>
  <%= render 'layouts/header2' %>
<% end %>
```

But what would the line `<% if "user is op page x" %>` need to be? That is, is there a Rails method that specifies the page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Couple things to mention here. 1 is, you only put stuff in layouts as alternative layouts to application.html.erb, this is so you can render a whole different template for a part of the app. Admin UI would have different layout for example.

For something that's more of a global partial for an app, i typically create partials folder under views: `app/views/partials` and put `_header1.html.erb` and `_header2.html.erb` in there.

Now for actually rendering them, this is where the controller method comes in handy.

In your view, update the if statement to:

```
<% if controller_name == "the_controller" && action_name == "the_action" %>
  <%= render partial: "partials/header1" %>
<% else %>
  <%= render partial: "partials/header2" %>
<% end %>
```

Just change the controller name and action name values as you need to. If you need to be more inclusive than that, (the header 2 should be for more than one action or controller), then I would recommend looking into `content_for`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check with `current_page?(route_path)`

```
<%= render partial: "partials/header#{current_page?(route_path) ? '1' : '2'}" %>" %>
```